# Pegar os primeiros caracteres de uma string

Tags: javascript

Como eu substituo uma string em JavaScript?

Eu estou pegando o nome da página.

```
var str = window.location.pathname;
```

O nome da url é `"/checkout/9/finalizacao"`
eu quero mudar para `"/checkout/"`

No caso os primeiros 10 caracteres.

Eu sei que existe o método sub string, porém eu não sei como utiliza-lo.

Não precisa colocar um código complicado, apenas a função que eu uso para tirar os 10 primeiros caracteres e como implementa-la. (Pois vou usa-la em um if depois)

```
if (pageName == "/carrinho/index" || str == "/checkout/"){
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Exactamente, podes usar o `.substring` para obter os caracteres 10 primeiros caracteres:

```
var str = window.location.pathname;
alert(str.substring(0,10));//intervalo de caracteres prentendido
```

Comment: Funcionou, eu usei:
var str = window.location.pathname;
str = str.substring(0,10);

Comment: Exacto, ficas com o valor na `str` como pretendes :)

Answer (score 5):

Neste caso eu separava as strings do URL e verificava o valor.

```
// Separa a string a partir do char "/" e retorna o 1 valor

var str = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1]

if (pageName == "/carrinho/index" || str == "checkout"){
}
```